# Is the で in という理由だけで a form of だ or the instrumental particle?

Tags: grammar, expressions, particle-で

I'm trying to figure out how to say "Maybe it's just because ____, but..." in Japanese, but I'm not sure how to place 'just because' in its own clause that way.

If I'm not mistaken, the expression '____という理由だけで' roughly translates to 'just because ____'. However, since I've only ever seen it used as part of a sentence about something else, like '友達がその本を推薦したという理由だけで読んだ', I can't tell whether the で in it acts as a particle, or the te-form of the copula.

Obviously, this is a problem when I'm trying to use the expression as a clause to add が to in my sentence. Does anyone know the proper way to do so?

Comment: 「という理由だけで」isn't wrong phrase at all, but it's commonly used as 「とういうだけで」so you might be able to find more information this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of で here fits the second [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%A7) definition:

> with, by, using: indicating the means by or with which something happens

The で here attaches to 理由, rather than だけ. 'Via' and 'per', and 'for' could also be suitable translations given the right context.

〇〇[という理由で](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E7%90%86%E7%94%B1%E3%81%A7)　&　〇〇[というわけで](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%82%8F%E3%81%91%E3%81%A7)　For that reason; on the grounds of _____.

I assume you want to add が to mean 'but'. If you show the specific sentence that you have in mind and attempt your own translation a fruitful answer may emerge.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The thing you said about attaching to 理由 gave me an idea: if i wanted to just say 'there is a reason', i would use ある, i.e. 理由がある. So I googled 'という理由だけである', and sure enough, it seems to be in use. I think that's probably the translation I'm looking for!

Comment: @AlphaModder Glad I could help ;)