# Is the で in というわけで the de-particle or the te-form of だ?

Tags: grammar, expressions, て-form, particle-で

Would the で in というわけで be analyzed as the te-form of da or the de particle? Both of them seem like they would fit, as the de particle can indicate cause/reason (as alluded to in this [similar question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65554/is-the-%E3%81%A7-in-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E7%90%86%E7%94%B1%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%81%A7-a-form-of-%E3%81%A0-or-the-instrumental-particle)) but [another question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27863/explanatory-particle-%E3%81%AE-comes-from-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7?rq=1) states that ので can be interpreted as "て form of the explanatory particle の with だ..." and indeed というわけだ is by itself a valid phrase.

Comment: I feel skeptical that those are really clearly different things. Do you have a good reference to explain the difference? I think you would be on firmer ground just asking somebody to clarify the meaning instead of try to explain it with such categorization.

Comment: @TimLovell-Smith The de particle seems to come from nite which seems to be historically distinct from the te-form of the da copula the https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11357/the-uses-etymology-of-%E3%81%A7 I don't have formal literature to cite for this, but multiple online sources seem to accord with there being a distinction between the two (at least historically)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

というわけで in the middle of a sentence is NOT interchangeable with というわけであって, というわけであり or というわけでして, so I think this type of で is a *particle* that marks a condition/scope.

Comment: Ah nice that seems like a good general test (pretty obvious in retrospect) to distinguish between the te-form of the copula vs the particle.